# Why does my link_to image_tag give syntax errors in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an image and a link which work separately, but when I try to combine them they don't. I have tried many permutations of `link_ to` and `image_tag` to no avail.

separately they work fine:

```
<%= image_tag 'functional-med.png', class:"nutricion" %>
<%= link_to 'functional med', 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```

however when I try:

```
 <%= link_to 'image_tag 'functional-med.png', class:"nutricion"', 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```

i get the error: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'

removing the single quotes gives the error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting =>

```
 <%= link_to image_tag 'functional-med.png', class:"nutricion", 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```

I have tried adding brackets inside and around the image_tag but keep getting syntax errors. 
another error I get , but dont understand is:
syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting ')'

I am not using a keyword "ensure" anywhere. I thought i was following the ruby api correctly http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Imagine you're ruby. How would you take that line apart? How do you know whether this string argument goes to `image_tag` or `link_to`? Sometimes you __need__ to use parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass a block to the `link_to`:

```
<%= link_to 'https://www.ifm.org/' do %>
  <%= image_tag 'functional-med.png', class:"nutricion" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('functional-med.png', class:"nutricion"), 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```

No need to add a bracket before image_tag

Comment: I tried: <%= link_to image_tag ('functional-med.png', class:"nutricion"), 'https://www.ifm.org/' %> but got the error: SyntaxError at /
syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ')'
...mage_tag ('functional-med.png', class:"nutricion"), 'https:/...
...                               ^
C:/Sites/bootstrapp3/app/views/pages/index.html.erb:13: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: or '[' or '.'
...al-med.png', class:"nutricion"), 'https://www.ifm.org/' );

Comment: Give the full URL `https://www.ifm.org/`. Also, remove semicolon after `ifm.org/`;

Answer (score 1):

I was working today with something like this

To mix both helpers just try

```
<%= link_to image_tag ('functional-med.png', class:"nutricion"), 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work

```
<%= link_to image_tag("create.png"), 'http://www.google.com' %>
```

General link_to with image tag to a controller action

```
    <%= link_to image_tag("create.png"), {action: 'action_name', controller: 'controller_name'} %>
```

You can add class / id attribute

```
<%= link_to image_tag("create.png"), {action: 'action_name', controller: 'controller_name'}, class: 'some-class' %>
```

Comment: `class` is with image, not the link.

Comment: I tried: <%= link_to image_tag ('functional-med.png'), "https://www.ifm.org/" %> but i got the error: NoMethodError at /
undefined method `symbolize_keys' for "https://www.ifm.org/":String

Comment: You should give the full URL <%= link_to image_tag ('functional-med.png'), 'https://www.ifm.org/' %> . The ';' after 'https://www.ifm.org/' is being added automatically. Ignore it.

Comment: Ignore the above comment by me. As you could see,     <%= link_to image_tag("create.png"), {action: 'action_name', controller: 'controller_name'} %>
it is expecting a hash over there.   Remove the space between image_tag and ('functional-med.png') and try <%= link_to image_tag('functional-med.png'), "ifm.org/"; %>

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('functional-med.png', class: 'nutricion'), 'https://www.ifm.org/' %>
```